# R pivot_wider or dcast to cast multiple columns

Tags: r, pivot, reshape

I am trying to cast multiple long dataset (`read_csv`) into wide data. The original sample data is the following:

```
ClassData <- read_csv("H:/Name Data.csv")

NAME    CATEGORY    NUMBER_CATEGORY
Amy     Low         180
Amy     Med         185
John    Low         118
John    Med         182
John    Med         185
```

I want the following:

```
NAME    CATEGORY 1  NUMBER_CATEGORY 1   CATEGORY 2  NUMBER_CATEGORY 2   CATEGORY 3  NUMBER_CATEGORY 3
Amy Low 180 Med 185 NULL    NULL
John    Low 118 Med 182 Med 185
```

Is there a way to achieve this with `pivot_wider`, `dcast` and/or `melt`? I am open to `gather()` and `spread()` as well.

Comment: Hi!. Please provide a reproducible example of your dataset ( you can copy the output od `dput()` function on a subset of your data: `dput(head(df))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
df1 %>%
   mutate(rn = rowid(NAME)) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = rn, values_from = c(CATEGORY, NUMBER_CATEGORY))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 7
#  NAME  CATEGORY_1 CATEGORY_2 CATEGORY_3 NUMBER_CATEGORY_1 NUMBER_CATEGORY_2 NUMBER_CATEGORY_3
#  <chr> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>                  <int>             <int>             <int>
#1 Amy   Low        Med        <NA>                     180               185                NA
#2 John  Low        Med        Med                      118               182               185
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(NAME = c("Amy", "Amy", "John", "John", "John"), 
    CATEGORY = c("Low", "Med", "Low", "Med", "Med"), NUMBER_CATEGORY = c(180L, 
    185L, 118L, 182L, 185L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R, you could do:

```
reshape(transform(df, time = ave(NAME, NAME, FUN = seq)), 
        v.names = c("CATEGORY", "NUMBER_CATEGORY"), dir="wide", idvar = "NAME", sep = "_")

  NAME CATEGORY_1 NUMBER_CATEGORY_1 CATEGORY_2 NUMBER_CATEGORY_2 CATEGORY_3 NUMBER_CATEGORY_3
1  Amy        Low               180        Med               185       <NA>                NA
3 John        Low               118        Med               182        Med               185
```